# heroku deployment npm error ' errno ENOENT'

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I am deploying with heroku and I found this error.

Usually I use `yarn` but after I change my laptop I start use `npm`

I believe this make issue.

what should I do? I want to use `yarn` not `npm`  for now `npm start` and `yarn start` both working.

```
sh: 1: yarn: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! design@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild: `yarn build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the design@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.W0OhY/_logs/2023-08-17T08_39_35_040Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

for now I did
`npm cache clean --force`

on my src I have, `package.json`, `yarn.lock`

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  },
```

Comment: Did you check the log file?

Comment: @technophyle do you mean yarn-error.log?

in the log file  -  ```
Trace: 
  Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-stripts: Not found```